# How to construct an Array to first compare and then add the input

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Due to being a beginner in react and js I'm having a hard time to construct an array properly,
I found an article on web according to that using concat method can construct an array. I have followed the same technique,
But my problem is it appends the data and dost compare if the same data already there.
**I want to compare the data before appending into array so no duplicate data gets into the array.**

My current code is:

```
const [input, setInput] = useState([]) // state

const handleOnChange = (userInput) => {
    // Add the userInput the list onChange of userInput
    // Save userInput to React Hooks
    
    setInput((input) => input.concat(userInput))
    console.log(input)
  }
```

Here userInput is and object with multiple strings values like

```
{id: 1 , ifYes: "Do this", ifNo : "Do something else"}
```

and if array has the item with id:1 then hitting it again it shouldn't append to the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array `find` to check if the array has an object with same id and if not then you can add the value

```js
const [input, setInput] = useState([]) // state

const handleOnChange = (userInput) => {
  // Add the userInput the list onChange of userInput
  // Save userInput to React Hooks
  const hasUserInput = input.find(userVal => userVal.id === userInput.id);
  if (!hasUserInput) {
    setInput((input) => input.concat(userInput));
    console.log(input)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the array contains an element with the id with `some(...)`.

```js
const [input, setInput] = useState([]) // state

const handleOnChange = (userInput) => {
    // Add the userInput the list onChange of userInput
    // Save userInput to React Hooks
    if(!input.some(i => i.id === userInput.id)){
        setInput((input) => input.concat(userInput))
    }
    console.log(input)
}
```

Comment: your answer will be right. But never execute function in `if` conditional statement. Reason is you wont able to get test the value when you put a debugger and also unit testing this code will be be tough