# How to stop adding duplicate data to Array in react.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I followed the approach as the answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71544521/how-to-construct-an-array-to-first-compare-and-then-add-the-input) suggested
The issue is that I want to construct an Array using setState and I dont; want to add duplicate data.

here is the sample data

```
const data = [
  {
    parentId: '1',
    userChoice: 'NO',
    child: []
  },
  {
    parentId: '2',
    userChoice: 'NO',
    child: []
  },
}
```

I'm catching the parentId from question.id from user input. If there is the same question then I don't want to concat into the array.

This is how I'm trying.

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]) // state

function arrayHandler(question) {
    const hasParentId = data.find((parentId) => question.id === parentId)
    // concat if array do not have any question with same id. 
    if (!hasParentId) {
      setData((data) => data.concat({ parentId: question.id, userChoice: 'NO', child: [] }))
    }
}
```

**But this is not working, How can I fix this ?**

Comment: Your `find` callback is accessing the object incorrectly, perhaps you meant to desctructure? `data.find(({parentId}) => question.id === parentId);` also since you're using the result as a boolean you might use [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead `const hasParentId = data.some(({parentId}) => question.id === parentId);`

Comment: Yes , you are right , thanks it's working now. Thanks @pilchard

Answer (score 1):

You can check if any of the elements in the `data` have a matching ID using [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and if not then you can use concat or just the spread operator to add the new object to the existing data.

```
function arrayHandler(question) {
  if (!data.some((d) => question.id === d.parentId)) {
    setData((data) => [...data, { parentId: question.id, userChoice: "NO", child: [] }]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that now it shold work

```
function arrayHandler(question) {
const hasParentId = data.find((object) => question.id === object.parentId)
// concat if array do not have any question with same id. 
if (!hasParentId) {
  setData((data) => data.concat({ parentId: question.id, userChoice: 'NO', child: [] }))
}
```

}